# Is there any word available for an incident occurred and vanished in front of eyes?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

I was confused, when one of my friends was writing his name on a lead from vapor of mouth: I saw his name for a few seconds and after that it automatically disappeared.

So what can I call this incident? Is there any word available for this incident?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the word "incident".

Comment: @Lohoris I guess v.k's English is not too good and he just wanted to say *phenomenon* or something like that. Let's wait for confirmation, shall we?

Comment: @Lohoris "experience" might work better.

Answer (score 9):

I guess you are referring to a **glimpse**

- a very brief passing look, sight, or view.

Comment: "It's this glimpse which inspires you -- like an occurrence." --Willem de Kooning

http://lynnecameron.com/blog/2014/1/30/im-like-a-slipping-glimpser

Answer (score 9):

Maybe [fleeting](https://www.google.com/search?q=fleeting&oq=fleeting) is the word your looking for?

> Fleet (pronunciation: flēt)
>
> verb: literary gerund or present participle: fleeting
>
> move or pass quickly. "a variety of expressions fleeted across his face"
>
> pass (time) rapidly. fade away; be transitory.

Answer (score 7):

**[Evanescent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evanescent)**: tending to vanish like vapor  -evanescently

Comment: This hint of a metaphor are very powerful, even for this literal application. You might strengthen your snswer with some synonyms.

Comment: I don't think anything works  as well here. 'Ephemeral' isn't as good. No, I'd leave the answer rather than weaken it with not-really-synonyms.

Answer (score 6):

**Ephemeral** - meaning something that lasts for a very short time.

Answer (score 2):

His name *[flash](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flash)ed before my eyes* then was gone.

> a thing that occurs suddenly and within a brief period of time, in
>   particular.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough 'reputation' to add this as a comment, so an answer it is...

Although not a single word, a combination of two of the other answers: a '**fleeting glimpse**' is perhaps what you're looking for. Think 'Pink Floyd - Comfortably Numb'!

Answer (score 0):

*[**Snap**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snap)* is used in this sense. Usually as "like a snap". It is related to how quick finger snapping is.

> *(n)* a quick, sudden action or movement, as the breaking of a twig.

---

As a phrase, there is ***[just like that](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/just+like+that)***:

> Suddenly and, sometimes, unexpectedly.
>
> *For example, The alarm went off, just like that , or And then they walked out, just like that .*

---

As an adjective there is ***[momentary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/momentary)*** (and its synonyms)

> lasting for a markedly brief time; *"a fleeting glance"; "fugitive hours"; "rapid momentaneous association of things that meet and pass"; "a momentary glimpse"*